# Call member function of an object stored in std::any

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, rtti, crtp

Suppose that I have a templated class, like so:

```cpp
template<class T, class V>
class MyClass
{
    public:
    MyClass(std::string const& name){
        s = name;
    }

    T return_var1() {
        return var1;
    }

    std::string s;
    T var1;
    V var2;
};
```

And I'm going to use it as shown:

```cpp
class AnotherClass {
    public:

    void some_func() {
        MyClass<int, double> my_var("test");
        std::pair<std::string, std::any> tmp_pair("test", my_var);
        my_vars.insert(tmp_pair);
    }

    void some_other_func() {
        auto tmp = my_vars["test"];
        
        // Any way to call member function without using std::any_cast<...> ?
        // For example, not like this:
        // (std::any_cast<MyClass<int, double>>tmp).return_var1()
        // But like this:
        std::cout << tmp.return_var1();
    }

    private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any> my_vars;
}
```

Is there any way to call member function of an object stored in std::any without knowing or using the type of the contained object? (**without using std::any_cast<>() as written on the comments above**)

Any solution is acceptable, e.g. inheriting MyClass from a base class with CRTP, using `std::variant` and so on.

The reason I need this is because I want to use a templated function as such:

```cpp
some_templated_function<decltype(my_var.var1)>();

// Or similarly,
some_templated_function<decltype(my_var.return_var1())>();
```

The purpose is to allow the user to register the types `<int, double>` only once, and use the typenames extensively, wherever needed.

Comment: `std::any` is basically unusable without knowing the original type. With `std::variant` you could use `std::visit`.

Comment: If you are sure your variables all have a `return_var1()` member then polymorphism may be the right solution instead. Otherwise it isn't clear how you intend to use your map.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I have a custom visitor implementation for `std::any` as well. I am able to register new types just as in `std::variant`. That approach still does not eliminate knowing and entering the type every time. The `map` is needed because `MyClass` may be initiated with any type, and they need to be stored somewhere.

Comment: @OkanBarut: "*I have a custom visitor implementation for `std::any` as well.*" If that's what you're doing, then you are using `any` for the wrong reasons. `any` is for communicating an object between two places who both know the type of the object, but the means of communication *doesn't* know or otherwise needs to be type-agnostic. `any` is not for doing polymorphism, which is when the receiver of an object is coded so that it doesn't know the exact type, only some pattern of behavior.

Comment: It's hard to give advice on how to solve this problem when we know so little about the nature of what the problem even is. Why do you want to use `any` (or any type) in this way? What are you trying to accomplish at a higher level? What are the pieces of code that are involved, what do they know about the objects, and why do they know those things and not others?

Comment: @NicolBolas I agree with your point of my usage of `any`. Nevertheless, I made an implementation similar to that of `variant` in order to allow extended usage due to demands. Anyway, what I'm trying to achieve is the stated at the bottom of the question: I'm trying to make the user register a type, that type may be a custom class, and let him forget about writing that class every time he uses a templated function like so: `some_func<class1, class2>()`. So instead of that, he shall use `some_func()` where template parameters are obtained from `MyClass` using `decltype`. Does this clarify?Thanks

Comment: @OkanBarut: "*I'm trying to make the user register a type*" What does that mean? How does the user go about this "registration" process? Where does the "type" get "stored" and later "accessed"? Because none of this sounds like a compile-time process. And C++ is a statically typed language. So what you're talking about is *nothing* like `variant`. In any case, you keep talking about mechanisms. I'm asking about what it is you're trying to accomplish. That is, *why* are you wanting to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible as long as the function that should be called has a known signature. I'm going to describe things using a more simple example as the one in your OP. Let's assume you have two classes that provide a member function `greet` with a fixed signature:

```
struct A
{
    void greet() const { std::cout<< "hello" << std::endl; }
};

struct B
{
    void greet() const { std::cout<< "goodbye" << std::endl; }
};
```

Using `std::any`, you can wrap any instances of these classes:

```
std::any a = A();
a = B();
```

In order to use the contained objects, however, you always have to know the exact type that is currently contained. This is unfortunate if you have numerous types or if the types are not defined by yourself (as in a library, for example). The basic approach to overcome this requirement is given in the following code:

```
struct any_caller
{
    template<typename T>
    any_caller(T object)
        : any_(object)
        , greet_([](std::any const& a){ return std::any_cast<T const&>(a).greet();})
    {}

    std::any any_;
    void (*greet_)(std::any const&);
    auto greet() const { return greet_(any_); }
};
```

The idea is the following:

- Define a function pointer with the exact signature of the  desired function to call. This will point to a lambda which performs the actual call of the function in the any-object.
- At the time of construction, and only there, you know the type of the object that is passed to `std::any`. You can use this information to set up a lambda that performs the `std::any_cast` and thereafter calls the desired function.
- This is a form of type erasure, as you are abstracting away from the actual object type that is stored, and, again, only works because you know the exact signature you want to call.

The code above can then be used as follows:

```
int main()
{
    any_caller c = A();
    c.greet();  //prints "hello"

    c = B();
    c.greet();  //prints "goodbye"
}
```

[Demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KzocYsEsY)

This basic example can further be extended to support more than one function, leading to a technique that has been called *Inheritance without pointers* described [here](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2021/01/29/inheritance-without-pointers/).